# Table not updating after mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an administrator.php which displays 300 records from a table called 'player'. Next to each record, there is an edit option which redirects you to edit.php and the 15 columns of that record (including the primary key - playerid) is displayed inside text boxes. Line of code below:

```
<a href='edit.php?playerid=".$query2['playerid']."'>Edit</a>
```

On edit.php you are able to change data of these columns. Upon submit, an update query is sent to update the table but unfortunately, it's not working. My error message continues to display ("testing for error..."); not sure why.

```
//Setups up the database connection
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("fantasymock", $link);

    if(isset($_GET['playerid'])) {
        $playerid = $_GET['playerid'];
        //Query to display results in input box
        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from player WHERE playerid = '$playerid'");
        $query2 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $playerid = $_POST['playerid'];
        $preranking = $_POST['preranking'];
        $playerlast = $_POST['playerlast'];
        $playerfirst = $_POST['playerfirst'];
        $position = $_POST['position'];
        $battingavg = $_POST['battingavg'];
        $run = $_POST['run'];
        $homerun = $_POST['homerun'];
        $rbi = $_POST['rbi'];
        $sb = $_POST['sb'];
        $win = $_POST['win'];
        $save = $_POST['save'];
        $strikeout = $_POST['strikeout'];
        $era = $_POST['era'];
        $whip = $_POST['whip'];
        //Query to update dB
        $query3 = mysql_query("UPDATE player SET playerid='$playerid', preranking='$preranking', playerlast='$playerlast', playerfirst='$playerfirst', position='$position', battingavg='$battingavg', run='$run', homerun='$homerun', rbi='$rbi', sb='$sb', win='$win', save='$save', strikeout='$strikeout', era='$era', whip='$whip' WHERE playerid='$playerid'");
        header("Location: administrator.php");
    } else {
        echo "Testing For Error....";

    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    Player ID:<input type="text" name="playerid" value="<?php echo $query2['playerid'];?>"/> <br/>
    Preranking:<input type="text" name="preranking" value="<?php echo $query2['preranking'];?>"/> <br/>
    Last Name:<input type="text" name="playerlast" value="<?php echo $query2['playerlast'];?>"/> <br/>
    First Name:<input type="text" name="playerfirst" value="<?php echo $query2['playerfirst'];?>"/> <br/>
    Position:<input type="text" name="position" value="<?php echo $query2['position'];?>"/> <br/>
    Batting Avg:<input type="text" name="battingavg" value="<?php echo $query2['battingavg'];?>"/> <br/>
    Runs:<input type="text" name="run" value="<?php echo $query2['run'];?>"/> <br/> 
    Homeruns:<input type="text" name="homerun" value="<?php echo $query2['homerun'];?>"/> <br/>
    Rbi:<input type="text" name="rbi" value="<?php echo $query2['rbi'];?>"/> <br/>
    Sb:<input type="text" name="sb" value="<?php echo $query2['sb'];?>"/> <br/>
    Wins:<input type="text" name="win" value="<?php echo $query2['win'];?>"/> <br/>
    Saves:<input type="text" name="save" value="<?php echo $query2['save'];?>"/> <br/>
    Strikeouts:<input type="text" name="strikeout" value="<?php echo $query2['strikeout'];?>"/> <br/>
    Era:<input type="text" name="era" value="<?php echo $query2['era'];?>"/> <br/>
    Whip:<input type="text" name="whip" value="<?php echo $query2['whip'];?>"/> <br/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

FYI: Every column in the table and tablename is spelled correctly, I've triple checked before posting. And I'm aware of MySQL injection. Can someone see a problem? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I just added an additional if statement `if($query3)` and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for POST variables, but you are getting to edit.php through a GET request. There isn't anything on `$_POST`. Therefore it drops down to the else of your if block and prints out `Testing For Error...`

Comment: all the text boxes are being populated from query2 when I click submit? So using the GET request to initially grab the variables conflicts with the POST when I submit?

Answer (score 0):

Your script in getting into the `else` part. That means there nothing it is getting as `$_POST['submit']`. Make sure that your `submit button` must have a `name` attribute as `submit`.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="" />
```

Comment: you dont see he have name ??

Answer (score 0):

please check what showing in `error.log` file. You may insert these lines at your `edit.php` file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

to display error.
Replace your else part by this for more detailed `mysql` errors

```
else{ echo "Testing For Error...." .mysql_error(); }
```